# make pattern file of augmented reality marker (.patt file) in android code

Tags: android, artoolkit, andar

Are there any instructions in Java to get a bitmap of an augmented reality marker and generate a pattern file from it?
I mean the pattern files (.patt) that are used in the AR augmented reality library. (This file includes a matrix with 0-255 values.)
for example in [this online pattern generator](http://flash.tarotaro.org/blog/2009/07/12/mgo2) we can upload a bitmap and it generates a pattern file.
Now, I want to have an instruction in Android code to do the same.
I know in ARtoolkit there is a `mk_patt` class that does that, but it is in C. I want to use it in Android.
Thanks a lot.